# Creating executable from python source file

Tags: python-2.7

I am following this guide for python 2.7 :
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html
I do all it says: I have a python file:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

print "hello world !\n"
```

And from terminal, in the directory where is the file I type:

```
chmod +x hello_world.py
```

The file is name hello_world.py; But nothing happens, it doesn't print "hello world\n".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give a bit more description: the chmod command changes the permissions of a file on a Unix-style system.  The +x in the command:

```
chmod +x hello_world.py
```

Sets the "Executable" bit for the hello_world.py file, thereby making it a script which can be executed.  Thus to run the script:

```
./hello_world.py
```

The ./ in front indicates that the file is in the current directory.  Alternatively, you can always run a script by invoking the python interpreter directly (regardless of permissions) like so:

```
python hello_world.py
```

Answer (score 4):

sorry if this is insultingly obvious, but

```
> chmod +x hello_world.py
```

only changes the file so that you *can* run it.  next you need to actually run the file by typing:

```
> ./hello_world.py
hello world !
```

Comment: And where's the executable? The .py one is source code.
Before doing this I could run it just typing: "python hello_world.py", this wasn't obvious, what's the difference and where's the executable?

Comment: python is not a compiled language.  what you are doing is making an executable shell script.  when you run it, as a script, the first line "says" to use python to run the program.  however, python does often create a bytecode file that is "half-compiled" - that is in the same directory and ends in ".pyc" (but i think this example is too simple to create one).